# Migrate from Prototype to jQuery (for newbie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, prototypejs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to use jQuery instead of Prototype (this one is what I am using at this time). I read many books, guides and tutorials but I still don't understand how I must use jQuery in my code (maybe it seams that nobody it "really" clear on this matter). Also, I have a lot of code written using Prototype so I would like to handle both at the same time and "progressively" migrate to jQuery.

I included the jQuery file in the layout file making `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'jquery' %>` so that the `<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1307515315" type="text/javascript"></script>` is present in the source code of all HTML pages. In order to avoid errors in the `application.js` file I added `jQuery.noConflict()` to the `application.js` file. Now, **what I must do?**

If I state a jQuery method in the `application.js` file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#test_id2').click(function() {
      alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
})
```

and I call it using

```
<%= link_to 'change1', '#', :id => 'test_id1' %>
```

it will work but I would like to put the above code in a separated `js` file. **How can I do and maj?**

**How I must name the JS file for a controller action? Where (in which folder) I must locate the related JS file? How can I state the `respond_to` method in my controllers?**

```
def edit
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # render edit.html.erb
    format.js # render... what file?! where?!
  end
end
```

Using Prototype I can write code directly in view files like the following:

```
<%= link_to_function( "change", :id => 'test_id2' ) do |page|
  page[:test_id3].toggle
  ...
end %>
```

**How can I do that using jQuery in view files?**

*Have you some advice?*

---

**UPDATE**

In my `edit.js.erb` file I have

```
<%
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#test_id1').click(function() {
      alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
})
%>
```

In the `edit.html.erb` file I have

```
<%= link_to 'Test link', '#', :id => 'test_id1' %>
```

But when I click the above link jQuery doesn't work (the *alert* method is not triggered). Furthermore, if I try to insert the JavaScript code directly in the view file, I get the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `document' for #<#<Class:0x00000102aa04d0>:0x00000102a75eb0>
```

Comment: With a tool like Firebug for Firefox, make sure that your `jquery` and your `edit.js` are loaded. --- See my edit also

Comment: @Lucas - In the HTML 'head' tag I can see only tht jquery library loaded, but not the edit.js.

Comment: Did you remove your misplaced `<% %>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differents things.

They are regular script that you can load the same way as you did with jquery:
You put them in your `public/javascript` directories and include them with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag YourNameFile %>
```

Note that I didn't add the **.js**. `javascript_include_tag` will do that for you.

Then you have **JS Templates**. It's like your Prototype views. Except you have Jquery inside.
So what you previously did works!
If you use

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # render edit.html.erb
  format.js # render edit.js.erb
end
```

It'll render `edit.js.erb` (you can find it in the **same** directory as your `edit.html.erb` file).

Then you can add your jQuery AND your 'ruby' in those files (exactly like prototype).
Just make sure that you load your jQuery.

If I missed something, add comment. :)

=== EDIT ===

In your Templates, you have to put `<% %>` only arounds Rails function !! Otherwise, it's supposed to be Javascript. So you `edit.js.erb` should looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#test_id1').click(function() {
      alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
})
```

Comment: Now it seams to render the 'edit.js.erb' file, but I would like to know how to insert and use in view files some inline jQuery code. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't do that. You should keep your JS separated from your HTML. If you really to, google it, you know that your jQuery is working !

Answer (score 0):

Your files should be named *.js.erb and be in a view folder (just like your *.html.erb), they should be named just like you name your *.html.erb files, i.e. edit.js.erb for edit action. You can write your ruby code in these files just like you did it for prototype (<% .... %>). Working with jQuery you usually work with selectors. For example, if you need to replace some html code on your page inside some `<div id=someid></div>` construction, you can do it in a way like this (# before element id is important):

```
$("#someid").html('<%= ... some ruby here, it can be render or anything ... %>')
```

If you need something to be inserted after some element, you do it like this:

```
$('<div>Some text</div>').insertAfter("#someid")
```

And so on.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. If you want to call alert when you click, just place alert('Clicked!') in your js.erb . upd: oh, nevermind.

Comment: Now it seams to render the 'edit.js.erb' file, but I would like to know how to insert and use in view files some inline jQuery code. Can you help me?